# Nodejs - Redirecting console.logs to a file in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a finalized functioning app, I need to add a log file for errors and accesses
There are already many console.logs in the whole app in many different folders and files

I read an old answer that suggested using this method below (which seems to be good theoretically), but it doesn't work

How should I do ?

```js
const access = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.cwd(), "logs", "access.log"), { flag: "a" });
const error = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(process.cwd(), "logs", "errors.log"), { flag: "a" });

console.log(path.join(process.cwd(), "logs", "errors.log"));

// redirect stdout / stderr
process.stdout.pipe(access);
process.stderr.pipe(error);
```

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* - well I'd say it does work. did you get an error? did a file get created? where did you run this code? what debugging steps did you try?

Comment: I get no errors, both files remain blank and everything is logged to the console, I have no idea how to debug this, I wrote this code just after all the imports of the server.ts (entry file) - I'm using ts-node to start the server